# How do I make flying enemies?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I figured all I had to do to make flying enemies was attach a set of wings to them, but doing so just turns them into hopping enemies, not flying ones. How do I make flying enemies? Is there a separate item for it, or is there something special I need to do in order to make the "hop wings" into "flying wings"?

Comment: Who ever flagged this "game design" off-topic doesn't seem to be aware of Mario Maker :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a Wing item in your tool bar; it just looks like a white wing. Simply drag that onto an enemy to attach them and make it fly.

Each enemy has slightly different behaviour with wings attached. For enemies that bounce around instead of fly, try placing them in Lakitu's cloud or the Clown Car.

Comment: The only enemies I know of that truly "fly" when they have wings is the Red Koopa and Para-Beetle.  Having said that, Lakitu's cloud and the Koopa Clown Car can be used to make other enemy types fly.

Comment: @Powerlord Yeah, and you can make a red koop by shaking aroudn the regular koopa. Never realized there was a difference between the two.